# PHP/Angularjs/Post data empty

Tags: php, angularjs

I do choose two fields (`month and origin`) in a form and submit it to an `AngularJS` controller, i am using 1.3.13 version packaged with Ionic framework.

Watching a `console.log` inside `then` method the values are populated correctly.

The `q.promisse` wich is returned have this value: `[object, object]`.

The list of the `HTML` template is not populated with the rigth expected values.

The values does not populate the `PHP POST` variable in the `PHP API`.

How can i populate the `POST` data ???

In my template i do submit to `search` method :

```
 <form method="post" ng-controller="AcpSearchCtrl" ng-submit="search(data)">
    <select name="month" ng-model="data.month">
      <option value="01">January</option>
```

And in my controller o do use `http.post` and a `promisse`:

```
.controller('AcpSearchCtrl', function($scope, ApiAcpSearch, $ionicLoading, $timeout, $http, ApiAcpEndpoint, $q) {  
  $scope.search = function(data) {
    $ionicLoading.show({
      noBackdrop: false,
      template: '<p>searching ...</p>'
    });
    var q = $q.defer();
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.submission = false;
    var param = function(data) {
          var returnString = '';
          for (d in data){
              if (data.hasOwnProperty(d))
                 returnString += d + '=' + data[d] + '&';
          }
          return returnString.slice( 0, returnString.length - 1 );
    };
    console.log('formData : '+$scope.formData);
    return $http({
      url:ApiAcpEndpoint.url,
      data : param($scope.formData),
      method : 'POST',
      headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
    }) 
    .then(function(data) {      
          q.resolve(data);          
          var acp = {};
          acp.qdata = [ data ];
          $scope.data = acp.qdata;
          $ionicLoading.hide();
          return q.promise;
      });
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AngularJS, by default, sends data in the JSON format. You won't find it in the regular PHP globals ($_REQUEST, $_POST or $_GET).

You have two ways to solve this issue:

Set the default *Content-Type* globally for AngularJS (just setting the header before the request will not work).

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
}]);
```

The alternative is that you handle the way AngularJS sends the data in PHP:

```
$angularJSData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// json_decode will create an object so if you need in array format
$angularJSData = (array)$angularJSData;
```

With this knowledge you can create a function or even your own global.

Comment: Thank´s Ricardo i tried but does not work, this must be a minor detail. Is there any kind of debugging i can do? i am printing and see `null` on the server side `PHP` script. I also tried to separate into a service and there the month and origin appear populated but still not into the `PHP API`.

Comment: I just get err_content_encoding

Comment: @ÂngeloRigo Post your whole form.

Comment: I pass the whole form, as you point and work´s ! thank you very much. My problem now is that at the `console log` i see the **correct data** filtered by month and origin coming from the webservice, but the template **does not update** to show this data and shows the unfiltered data instead . I have the `$scope.data` with the real data on the `console.log`, how do i force an update or return the correct data ?

Comment: @ÂngeloRigo Without knowing your full requirements (or the ionic framework) here's my suggestion. I think you are complicating matters by using promises in this situation `$http({ /* code */ ).success(function(data) { /* More stuff */ });`. Do you understant what I mean?

Comment: Yes ! i am new to angularjs, but i will try to use http.post instead of a promisse, and see what the success section returns.

Comment: Using http post just work´s! i see the correct data at console.log, now i will track a ng-repeat duplicate, try to use track by $index but iterate over each character.