# Angularjs file upload in put method not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, laravel-5

I have a simple todos application in which i am trying to upload a photo along with a single todo. Now i have created this factory function that takes care of the creation of the todo

```
  todosFactory.insertTodo = function(todo){
    return $http.post(baseUrl, todo, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type' : undefined
      },
      transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter){
        var formData = new FormData();
        angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
            formData.append(key, value);
        });
        return formData;
      }
    });
  };
```

And the factory update method looks like this

```
  todosFactory.updateTodo = function(id, todo){
    return $http.put(baseUrl + '/' + id, todo, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type' : undefined
      },
      transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter){
        var formData = new FormData();
        angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
            formData.append(key, value);
        });
        return formData;
      }
    });
  };
```

The insertTodo is working as expected but the updateTodo is not posting data to the server. I am using laravel for the API and the update API endpoint has this code

```
dd(Input::all(), Input::file('cover_photo'));
```

This shows that noting was posted in the request. And if i change the put to post in the updateTodo factory method it starts working. Am i missing some extra headers or something ?

#### Update

If i remove both the `transformRequest` and `headers` form the updateTodo method, the text data is successfully received on the server but the the file doesn’t.
 And if i just remove the `headers` nothing gets posted

#### Update

I am using the PHP server that comes with laravel using this command

```
php artisan serve
```

#### Update

Thanks to @Ricardo's answer i was able to get the submitted data using this code

```
router->put('/todos/{id}', function($id){
    $stream = file_get_contents("php://input");
    echo $stream;
    die();
});
```

I am getting the stream in this format

```
-----------------------------3643739756006088191021064137
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"

5
-----------------------------3643739756006088191021064137
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

Image Todo
-----------------------------3643739756006088191021064137
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="complete"

0
-----------------------------3643739756006088191021064137
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="created_at"

2015-10-02 06:28:10
-----------------------------3643739756006088191021064137
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="updated_at"

2015-10-02 06:28:10
-----------------------------3643739756006088191021064137
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cover_photo"; filename="Dragon-Falls-Venezuela-5.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

�����JFIF��H�H������Exif��MM�*�����i������������������z���,����UNICODE��C�R�E�A�T�O�R�:� 
�g�d�-�j�p�e�g� �v�1�.�0� �(�u�s�i�n�g� �I�J�G� �J�P�E�G� �v�6�2�)�,� �q�u�a�l�i�t�y� �=� �9�0�
```

Now i need to parse this raw format. I have found two php methods that other people have suggested http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-parse-str.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php but both of them are not working properly and do not give an array like $_GET or $_POST.

Comment: Did you define a request mapping for PUT on the server side?

Comment: Yes i did 
$router->put('/todos/{id}', function($id){
    $data = Input::all();
    $cover = Input::file('cover_photo');
    dd($data, $cover);
  });

Comment: If you switch it to a post can you check if the body is coming through? Also remove your transformRequest, let's just get it posting first.

Comment: I used https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload and it worked with PUT ;)

Comment: It starts working when i switched it to post instead of put @MathewBerg

Comment: Even if you left the transformRequest? (i.e. post but with transformRequest still)

Comment: i met same problem which turns out nginx conf error,maybe you should check it too.

Comment: @RayCheng i am using the php server that comes with laravel using this command  `php artisan serve` , and what configuration option you changed to make it work ?

Comment: @SajjadAshraf use nginx must let server support PUT method.not sure laravel server

Comment: @SajjadAshraf I have edited my answer with information that can help taking into account the edit you have made.

Answer (score 1):

[This piece from the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php) discusses the PUT method and file uploads (multipart/form-data).

I can't quote any parts from it because I think everything is important. You should read it in detail but to summarize it's not possible without changes to your Apache configuration and creation of auxiliary scripts.

With Laravel you should use [Form Method Spoofing](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#form-method-spoofing) (basically a variable called `_method`) and keep on using POST. The `_method` will allow you to call Laravel's PUT action correctly.

---

**Edit**

AngularJS, by default, sends data in the JSON format which explains why you cannot access the data with the `$_POST` global. I have answered this in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31455835/541884) which explains what you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to serialize the file on the server side and if you sending a file then attach a custom header and appropriately handle that header requests on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Create you `formData` upfront -> you don't need the transformer for that.
Add `transformRequest : angular.identity` to your `HTTP` headers.
Your code should look similar to the snippet below:

```
$http.post('/api/endpoint', formData, {
  transformRequest : angular.identity,
  headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
})
.success(function (data) {
  // do stuff with data
})
.error(function (error) {
  // recover from an error
});
```

Angular identity does nothing more than to spit back your form data: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.identity

Comment: This isn't using `put`.